# Links are only working on desktop but not mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

We have a slider on our homepage which is working just fine on desktop view, but nothing happens on smartphone or tablet view.

If I open the developer console and switch to a smartphone view, then nothing happens on click. (You might have to reload the page a few times until the bug will be noticeable)

This is the slider I am talking about:

[image]

Website: https://www.blizz-z.de/

```
<div id="homeslider-revolution" style="overflow: visible;">
    <div class="revolution-slider revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive" id="revslider-227" style="height: 222px;">
        <ul style="display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; max-height: none;">
            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 18; opacity: 1;"><a href="/aktionen"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/slider/blizz-z-hp-slider-bauplattenmailing-19.jpg" alt="Jet Bauplatten mit satten Rabatten"></a></li>
            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 18; opacity: 1;"><a href="/produkte-bewerten"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/slider/blizz-z-hp-slider-bewertung-19.jpg" alt="Produkt bewerten &amp; Überraschung erhalten"></a></li>
            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 18; opacity: 1;"><a href="/newsletter-bestellen"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/slider/slider-newsletter/newsletter-bestellen-de.jpg" alt="Newsletter abonnieren"></a></li>
            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 20; opacity: 1;"><a href="/anwendungstechnik/abdichtungsnormen.html"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/slider/slider-abdichten/abdichtungsnormen.jpg" alt="Abdichtungsnormen"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tp-loader" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="tp-bannertimer" style="visibility: hidden; width: 83.8696%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-bannershadow tp-shadow1" style="width: 820px;"></div>
    <div class="tp-bullets simplebullets round hidebullets" style="bottom: 6px; left: 50%; margin-left: -39px;">
        <div class="bullet first"></div>
        <div class="bullet"></div>
        <div class="bullet"></div>
        <div class="bullet last selected"></div>
        <div class="tpclear"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 170px; margin-top: -22px; left: 0px;" class="tp-leftarrow tparrows default hidearrows"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 170px; margin-top: -22px; right: 0px;" class="tp-rightarrow tparrows default hidearrows"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

The z-index of the highest slider is 20, while the others is 18. There is no other element above the slider image which blocks clicking.

It does not work in Chrome <s>and FireFox</s> but it works on Apple iOS browser. I am running out of ideas and start to think that this is a browser bug

**Update:**

[image]

I am using Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

I made a [bug report](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10847096?hl=en).

Comment: I have tried many times and it's working fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: For the firefox-side of your problem, it's a [well known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1502909), that should no happen on recent versions. What is your firefox version ?

Comment: I am using version 68.0.1 (64-Bit), but I tried it again just now and it works. But it was not working last week.

Comment: try disable the touch swipe and check again.

Comment: @SumitPatel, It works on FireFox for now, so this seems to be a chrome bug

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
.tp-simpleresponsive a{
    border:1px solid;
    display:block;
}
```

The problem is that your inline link in mobile not scale height with the image.

Comment: Why the border?

Comment: This was actually hard to see, anchors's default display is already set to "block"

Comment: Hi, the border is just to let you understand, I use it on development to identify the part of html in which I'm working, the borders without the block has show me the problem and helped me to fix it. You can remove it

Comment: I added the code at runtime by opening the developer console and adding a <style> block to my page, but it still fails. Do I have to add this before runtime?

Comment: @red, I added the new style and even changed `display: block;` to `display: block !important;`. It draws the border, but the link does not work.

Comment: give me some time to see

Comment: @red, I added a gif to my question so that you can see that it is not working. Nothing happens on click. I think this is a chrome bug.

Comment: Hi, I'm not understand why this happen, I've find that if you use chrome directly as device the link not work, if you start the site normal and then change to device it work. Maybe some js in responsive has a preventdefault() in the onclick event?

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah I faced the same problem , my `navlinks` were working fine in desktop but not opening for mobile devices.

All i did was , assigned a very big **z-index** number to my **navlinks**

```
#mainnav {
   position: absolute;
   font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
   z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your code in the browser you will find a div with the class of dropdown-backdrop.
This is created automatically by the browser. Try to Hide it by the following method, your code will start working.

In the CSS file:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    display: none;
}
```